# How to separate array with 5 numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with 5 numbers from 1 to 6. I can have arrays with different configurations from [1,1,1,1,1] trough [1,2,3,4,5] to for example [1,2,2,2,6]. 
The array is sorted. For example:

```
var table = [1,1,1,1,1];
```

or

`var table = [1,2,2,4,5];`

or

`var table = [1,2,2,2,6];`

I have to divide it on this conditions:
if there are exactly three the same numbers I have to group them together and leave another numbers as separate arrays with one element so it would be:

```
var table = [[1,1,1],[1],[1]];
```

or

`var table =  [[1],[2,2,2],[6]];`

or if there are not 3 the same numbers it should look like:

`var table = [[1],[2],[2],[4],[5]];`

I tried with iterations etc but apparently it's beyond my imagination.

I tried with condition like this:

```
    for (var i=0;i<table.length;i++){
      if(table[i] == table[i+1] && table[i] == table[i+2]){
// sorting here 
}}
```

But it won't work for array with 5 the same numbers like:

```
 var table = [1,1,1,1,1];
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of what you've tried, otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: stop giving negative points he is a new member, just explain to him to include some code so we can help

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not even understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you need to maintain the order of the initial array? What would you expect with an input array such as `[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]`?

Comment: If you are trying to think how to approach it, forget about having a computer.  Just walk through how you'd do it if you had to it by hand.  Even to the point of tearing up pieces of paper and having cups for the arrays you filling up.  Write down the steps in English (or your favorite language).  Then you can start worrying about Javascript.

Comment: Code is not strictly necessary, but we need to understand what you are trying to do, maybe why you are trying to do it, and what you have tried so far to determine where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry guys if I posted something no. Asking on stack is usually my last try if I can't find something myself.

Comment: @zzzzBov: MCVEs are for debugging (or, more generally, problems with existing code). They are not a suitable tool to asses problems that prevent the creation of the code in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost doing good. I think if you change a little bit in your code like

```
    var table = [1,1,1,1,1];
    var resultTable=[];
    var grpTable=[];

 for (var i=0;i<table.length;i++){
   if(table[i] == table[i+1] && table[i] == table[i+2] && i<3){
   grpTable[0]=table[i];
   grpTable[1]=table[i+1];
   grpTable[2]=table[i+2];
   resultTable.push(grpTable);
   i=i+2;
}
else{
     resultTable.push([table[i]]);
     }}
 console.log(resultTable);
```

it will satisfy your all conditions.

Answer (score 2):

```
var yourArray = [1,1,2,3,4,4];

var newArrays = {};
for( var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++ ){
    if(typeof(newArrays[yourArray[i]]) == "undefined"){
        newArrays[yourArray[i]] = [];
    }
    newArrays[yourArray[i]].push(yourArray[i]);
}
```

Would this be a possible solution for you? Result in this:

```
{
    1:[1,1],
    2:[2],
    3:[3],
    4:[4,4]
}
```

Comment: Almost there. This produces an object with numeric keys as opposed to an array, which is what the OP is trying to get.

Comment: You could simply reduce the values array of that result object, something like: `Object.values(result).reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next.length >= 3 ? [next] : next), [])`...

Comment: Almost there. I edited my post so it's more clear now. But thanks for your answer. I'll try make something out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this end in an array like this:
 [ [1,1],[2],[3],[4,4] ]

```
var yourArray = [1,1,2,3,4,4]

var newArraysObject = {};
for( var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++ ){
    if(typeof(newArraysObject[yourArray[i]]) == "undefined"){
        newArraysObject[yourArray[i]] = [];
    }
    newArraysObject[yourArray[i]].push(yourArray[i]);
}
var newArraysArray = [];
for (var property in newArraysObject) {
    newArraysArray.push(newArraysObject[property]);
}
```

Comment: Ok but condition for grouping more than one element in array is if there is 3 the same numbers. So if there would be array like: `var yourArray = [1,1,2,3,4,4]`  it should look like`var yourArray = [[1],[1],[2],[3],[4],[4]]` but if there is `var yourArray = [1,1,1,3,4,4]` it should look like var `yourArray = [[1,1,1],[3],[4],[4]]`

Answer (score 1):

You could take a counter for same values and group three same values in a single array.

```js
function group(array) {
    return array.reduce((count => (r, v, i, a) => {
        if (a[i - 1] !== v) {
            count = 0;
        }
        r.push([v]);
        count++;
        if (count === 3) {
            r.push([].concat(...r.splice(-3, 3)));
            count = 0;
        }
        return r;
    })(0), []);
}

console.log(group([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
console.log(group([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(group([1, 2, 2, 2, 6]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Better solution.